OS error while trying to import OCPCalculator
I am having trouble importing a calculator (OCPCalculator). I uninstalled existing torch version and installed a version that supports the task. but it’s still giving me an OS error.
Code:
from fairchem.core.common.relaxation.ase_utils import OCPCalculator
import ase.io
from ase.optimize import BFGS

Error:
OSError   Traceback (most recent call last)/var/folders/n7/96_5cstj2sn6g5ll0b979w380000gn/T/ipykernel_49125/1241704498.py in <module>
----> 1 from fairchem.core.common.relaxation.ase_utils import OCPCalculator
  2 import ase.io
  3 from ase.optimize import BFGS
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fairchem/core/common/relaxation/ase_utils.py in <module>
 24 
 25 from fairchem.core.common.registry import registry
---> 26 from fairchem.core.common.utils import (
 27     load_config,
 28     setup_imports,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fairchem/core/common/utils.py in <module>
 30 import torch
 31 import torch.nn as nn
---> 32 import torch_geometric
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/sitepackages/torch_geometric/__init__.py in <module>
 11 import torch_geometric.loader
 12 import torch_geometric.transforms
---> 13 import torch_geometric.datasets
...
384             self._handle = handle

OSError: 
dlopen(/Users/roshnidantuluri/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/sitepackages/torch_cluster/_version_cpu.so, 0x0006): 
Symbol not found: __ZN3c1017RegisterOperatorsD1Ev
Referenced from: <6A95460A-9602-33F2-92B2-6A9C90B59457>/Users/roshnidantuluri/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch_cluster/_version_cpu.so
Expected in:     <709C1DF5-D253-3C66-87E2-C99FD3A259DF>/Users/roshnidantuluri/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cpu.dylib


Please check the edit

You would also need to install torch_geometric and torch_scatter
packages to use modules from fairchem.core. Create a venv or anaconda environment with Python 3.10 or newer (I used Python 3.10.14) and follow these installation steps:
pip install fairchem-core
pip install torch_geometric torch-scatter

Then run the following as per their documentation:
from fairchem.core import OCPCalculator 


I have the fairchem-core, torch geometric and torch scatter installed already. It still gives me this error despite having them.

From your error traceback, I see that you are using python 3.9. Can you try with a new environment with Python 3.10 and follow the steps I suggested?

I just tested with Python 3.9 and it's working on my end. I guess you are having a depedency issue between the libraries. Can you install these particular libraries: torch-2.4.0, torch-scatter-2.1.2, torch_geometric-2.5.3?

I created a venv (with Python 3.10.2) and still had trouble downloading torch-scatter. But, I tried installing the specific versions you mentioned and that seemed to work! Thanks a lot! It was very frustrating that I couldn't even import stuff to get the code running.
